# Exercise conditional expectation

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve the next problem about conditional expectation:

Let ($\Omega$,$\mathcal{F}$,P) be a probability space given by $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$,$\mathcal{F}=P(\Omega)$ and

$P(w)= \begin{cases} 1/8, &\mbox{if } \omega = 1,4 \\ 1/4, &\mbox{if } \omega = 2  \\ 1/2, &\mbox{if } \omega = 3 \end{cases}$

Let $ \mathcal{G}_1=\{\emptyset,\Omega\} \mbox{, } \mathcal{G}_2=\{\emptyset,\Omega,\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\} \mbox{, } \mathcal{G}_3=\{\emptyset,\Omega,\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\} $ sub $\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{F}$. Let the random variable

$X(\omega)= \begin{cases} -1, &\mbox{if } \omega = 1,3 \\ 2, &\mbox{if } \omega = 2,4 \end{cases}$

Find $E(X|\mathcal{G}_i) \mbox{ for } i=1,2,3$

Someone can help me?

Thanks you

Comment: You just have to plug in these values in the definition of the conditional expectation. So, do you know the definition? If you do, try to calculate $E(X, \mathcal{G}_{1})$ and show your work. Otherwise, first look up the definition and then calculate $E(X, \mathcal{G}_{1})$.

Comment: How this can get three upvotes escapes me. @upvoters Care to explain your vote for a question with no context, whose best answer would probably read: "Apply the definition"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do the case $i=3$. The other cases are similar and you should try to do them yourself.

Begin by noting that $\mathcal{G}_3$ is generated by a finite partition of $\Omega$. Since the conditional expectation $E(X \mid \mathcal{G}_3)$ is $\mathcal{G}_3$-measurable by definition, it must be constant on the atoms of $\mathcal{G}_3$, which are $\{ 1,3\}$ and $\{2,4 \}$. Therefore, by the defining property of conditional expectations, we have (almost surely)

$$E(X \mid \mathcal{G}_3) = \frac{\int_{\{1,3\}} X dP}{P(\{1,3 \})} \mathbf{1}_{\{1,3 \}} +  \frac{\int_{\{2,4\}} X dP}{P(\{2,4 \})} \mathbf{1}_{\{2,4 \}} \\ = -\frac{5/8}{5/8}\mathbf{1}_{\{1,3 \}} + \frac{6/8}{3/8}\mathbf{1}_{\{2,4 \}} = (-1)\mathbf{1}_{\{1,3 \}} + (2)\mathbf{1}_{\{2,4 \}}.$$

Notice that $E(X \mid \mathcal{G}_3) = X$ a.s. This is because $X$ is itself $\mathcal{G}_3$-measurable. So the calculations weren't really needed, though hopefully they're instructive.